# Mercurial with WebUI

Tags: mercurial, debian, webui

I searched a little and did not find anything interesting. I'm looking for a guide on how to install Mercurial server with a nice WebUI.
CollabNet Subversion under Windows to the Edge and I'm happy, but a lot of people write and say that Mercurial is better, so I want to evaluate this myself.

I am looking for a tutorial, or for any WebUI for Mercurial.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure how feature-rich you want the Web UI to be, but a good place to start would be with hgweb.

The simplest way to get something up and running is with the built-in web server from the 'hg serve' command:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/hgserve

If you want something a little more involved for multiple repositories being served through a web server like httpd, here are some initial instructions to take a look at:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep

If you need something more like a local Github, maybe take a look at [RhodeCode](https://rhodecode.com) (disclaimer, never used personally)

Comment: I know these systems. It's enough for me. I need statistics, setting up new users, adding new repositories, login.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw a web app for Mercurial repository administration linked on another question : [phpHgAdmin](https://bitbucket.org/joshjcarrier/phphgadmin/wiki/Home).

Apparently, you can manage your repositories and create new users, but no statistics.

I never tested it, but you maybe want to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Phabricator's Diffusion supports Mercurial: https://www.phacility.com/phabricator/diffusion/